# php alert box with ok and cancel buttons

Tags: javascript, php, alert

I have a **php code (little bit javascript as well)** as shown below in which which an **alert message** is displayed when **second user** tries to login the form with **one user already logged in**.

The issue which I am having right now is on clicking **ok in the alert box**, it goes inside the **if block** but it on clicking cancel it doesn't go inside the **else block** instead it goes 
inside the **if block again**.

```
<?php
    $message = "user " . $row['user_name'] . " is logged in. Do you want to take over ?";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>confirm('$message');</script>";
    if(confirm)
    {
        $stmt1=$connect->prepare("UPDATE trace_users SET write_access='0' WHERE write_access='1'"); // revoke write access of all users
        $stmt1->execute();
    }
    else
    {
        echo "I am in else block";  // Line A
        $stmt1=$connect->prepare("UPDATE trace_users SET write_access='1' WHERE write_access='0'"); // revoke write access of all users
        $stmt1->execute();
    }
?>
```

I have added **Line A/Line B** for debugging purpose. On clicking button **Ok** button Line A is called and on clicking **Cancel** button, Line A is called again.

Comment: The PHP code renders out HTML and sends that to the client. Only then is the JavaScript executed and PHP has *moved on to other things. In computer terms a hundred years have passed since the HTML was sent over the network to the client, it's ancient history by the time the browser actually executes it. You cannot mix JavaScript in the middle of PHP like this.

Comment: JS responds to the Browser, not to the Server. You're mixing things. You can use JS to send AJAX to the server - if you want...

Comment: **"Its worse that that Jim"** The javascript does not run until it gets to the browser,

Comment: So `confirm` will not exist in PHP (its not a PHP variable anyway (no $))so you shoudl be getting at least one error

Comment: A) Avoid using `alert()` in your code. It's annoying and rage-inducing because of how it can steal focus and lock up your browser when you least expect it. B) Use links styled as buttons on the page that links to another update script that performs the database operation. C) Use AJAX if necessary.

Comment: If you want to tell the server (your php code that wants to run sql queries) that something has happened on the client (the code where the user clicks ok or cancel) you *have* to send a request of some kind back to the server to tell it what the user did.  Load a url with a querystring, submit a form, do some ajax, mess with websockets - those are the only ways.

Comment: I used this [article](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/web-development/threads/491266/alert-box-ok-and-cancel) to write my code but I believe its wrong. As you mentioned confirm doesn't exist in php. I am wondering if you can give me pointer how to approach this question.

Comment: @tadman we need to tell Apple that.

Comment: @RoboRobok It's annoying on every platform, in every browser.

Comment: Sure. It drives me nuts when Safari displays alerts about being offline. Or iOS displaying 20% and 10% battery alert 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick example to get you started:

*`index.php`*

```html
<?php
//....
$user =  "John Doe"; // $row['user_name'];
$message = "User $user is logged in. Do you want to take over?";

if (isset($_GET['takeover'])) {
    if ($_GET['takeover'] == "confirm") {
        // $stmt1 = $connect->pre......etc
        exit(json_encode(["message" => "Access confirmed"])); // Send response to JS
    } else {
        // $stmt1 = $connect->pre......etc
        exit(json_encode(["message" => "Access revoked"])); // Send response to JS
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>

  <h1>MY USER INTERFACE</h1>

  <script>
    const takeover = confirm("<?= $message ?>");
    fetch(`?takeover=${takeover ? "confirm" : "revoke"}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
      });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

- the server will "strip" PHP tags before serving the page, but the echoed values will remain. I.e: `$message` inside the JavaScript code.
- On Document ready the `confirm()` triggers, and a boolean value is carried in JS.
- Depending on that value simply fetch the same file (or any other if you want) using a GET request `somepagename.php?takeover=confirm`
- Listen in PHP for `$_GET` requests and respond to the AJAX request with a JSON response.
- Open console, and see the server respond with the adequate message object data.

Happy coding.

Comment: Hey, when I login, I get the alert with no message. The alert has Ok and Cancel buttons, thats it.

Comment: @user1950349 if you save the above say as `index.php` and you run it using a PHP server i.e: `php -S localhost:8000` you'll see it working. Just don't forget to F12 to open the browser console to see the `console.log()` responses from server.

Answer (score 0):

On your userpage.php you have the Log In:

```
<a href="confirm_login.php?user_name=" . $row['user_name']>Log In</a>
```

In your confirm_login.php you have the confirmation with the two options:

```
$message = "user " . $_GET[user_name] . " is logged in. Do you want to take over ?";
<a href="userpage.php?confirm=yes">Yes</a>
<a href="userpage.php?confirm=no">No</a>
```

Now when you choose option you redirect back to userpage.php:

```
if ( $_GET[confirm] == "yes" ) {
    $stmt1=$connect->prepare("UPDATE trace_users SET write_access='0' WHEREwrite_access='1'");
    $stmt1->execute();
} else if ( $_GET[confirm] == "no" ) {
    $stmt1=$connect->prepare("UPDATE trace_users SET write_access='1' WHERE write_access='0'"); // revoke write access of all users
    $stmt1->execute();  
}
```

This is the plain PHP method described in your article. As other cool guys say you can use AJAX to not change URL.